# Headless Pi server over Wifi

Tags: networking, wifi, archlinux, headless

I bought new Pi b+. So i found my hungry wifi dongle can work on it well, I decided to put my Pi running headlessly over wifi.
But problem is if wifi disconnects, the Pi wont reconnect.

I'm using Arch Linux.

The netctl profile I use:

```
   Description='wifi "mikroskeem" with ip 192.168.1.192'
   Interface=wlan0
   Connection=wireless
   Security=wpa
   ESSID='mikroskeem'
   Key='<ransom key>'
   IP=static
   Address='192.168.1.192/24'
   Gateway='192.168.1.1'
   DNS=('192.168.1.1')
   ExecUpPost='/usr/bin/ntpd -gq || true'
```

EDIT: I'm using Arch Linux, so no /etc/network/interfaces

I've enabled netctl-auto@wlan0

I've tried Wicd, but if i set IP manually, Pi can't reach internet(LAN works, ping google doesn't)

What do i need to change in that profile?

Comment: I would recommend you to set static IP anyway. Are you sure you can't *reach internet*? Try to ping directly an ip `ping 8.8.8.8`. Sometimes it's just DNS what's cause problems. Pinging specific IP could help.

Comment: Post the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: @kotrfa 8.8.8.8 didn't work

Comment: @Milliways I use Arch Linux, no `/etc/network/interfaces` for me. Netctl handles this

Comment: I think I fixed it by adding `Restart=always` at the end of netctl configuration. Let's see if network goes off after 3hrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed problem myself, by adding `Restart=always` at the end of netctl configuration.